# Codrops JavaScript overlay, undefined is not a function error

Tags: javascript, function, overlay, thumbnails

I want to use a tut form Codrops to make overlays for my portfolio. When clicking on a thumbnail, the project overlay should open. Here's the tut/markup/javascript: http://tympanus.net/codrops/2014/02/06/fullscreen-overlay-effects/ (I use example number 7, 'Content Push')

But the problem is that the 'trigger-overlay' is an id, and not a class, because in the tut the example uses just 1 button. I have multiple thumbnails, so I changed the var triggerBttn from 'getElementById' to 'getElementsByClassName'

```
    (function() {
    var container = document.querySelector( 'div.pagewrapper' ),
        triggerBttn = document.getElementsByClassName( 'trigger-overlay' ),
        overlay = document.querySelector( 'div.overlay' ),
        closeBttn = overlay.querySelector( 'button.overlay-close' );
        transEndEventNames = {
            'WebkitTransition': 'webkitTransitionEnd',
            'MozTransition': 'transitionend',
            'OTransition': 'oTransitionEnd',
            'msTransition': 'MSTransitionEnd',
            'transition': 'transitionend'
        },
        transEndEventName = transEndEventNames[ Modernizr.prefixed( 'transition' ) ],
        support = { transitions : Modernizr.csstransitions };

    function toggleOverlay() {
        if( classie.has( overlay, 'open' ) ) {
            classie.remove( overlay, 'open' );
            classie.remove( container, 'overlay-open' );
            classie.add( overlay, 'close' );
            var onEndTransitionFn = function( ev ) {
                if( support.transitions ) {
                    if( ev.propertyName !== 'visibility' ) return;
                    this.removeEventListener( transEndEventName, onEndTransitionFn );
                }
                classie.remove( overlay, 'close' );
            };
            if( support.transitions ) {
                overlay.addEventListener( transEndEventName, onEndTransitionFn );
            }
            else {
                onEndTransitionFn();
            }
        }
        else if( !classie.has( overlay, 'close' ) ) {
            classie.add( overlay, 'open' );
            classie.add( container, 'overlay-open' );
        }
    }

    triggerBttn.addEventListener( 'click', toggleOverlay );
    closeBttn.addEventListener( 'click', toggleOverlay );

})();
```

The code depends on [classie.js](https://github.com/desandro/classie/blob/master/classie.js)

But now i get the error

> Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

on the line:

```
triggerBttn.addEventListener( 'click', toggleOverlay );
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Note the plural form in `getElementsByClassName()` -- the method returns a *list* of elements. Therefore, `triggerBttn` is such a list, and invoking `addEventListener()` on it will fail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the simple issue is that they are not defining the rest of variables after "closeBttn ",this code block the rest of variable.

Fault

```
closeBttn = overlay.querySelector( 'button.overlay-close' );
```

It should be

```
closeBttn = overlay.querySelector( 'button.overlay-close' ),
```

So the final code will be

```
var triggerBttn = document.getElementById( 'trigger-navbar' ),
        navbar = document.querySelector( 'section.navbar' ),
        closeBttn = navbar.querySelector( 'a.navbar-close' ),
        navClick = navbar.querySelector( 'section.navbar nav ul li a' ),
        transEndEventNames = {
            'WebkitTransition': 'webkitTransitionEnd',
            'MozTransition': 'transitionend',
            'OTransition': 'oTransitionEnd',
            'msTransition': 'MSTransitionEnd',
            'transition': 'transitionend'
        },
        transEndEventName = transEndEventNames[ Modernizr.prefixed( 'transition' ) ],
        support = { transitions : Modernizr.csstransitions };

        function toggleOverlay() {
        if( classie.has( navbar, 'open' ) ) {
            classie.remove( navbar, 'open' );
            classie.add( navbar, 'close' );
            var onEndTransitionFn = function( ev ) {
                if( support.transitions ) {
                    if( ev.propertyName !== 'visibility' ) return;
                    this.removeEventListener( transEndEventName, onEndTransitionFn );
                }
                classie.remove( navbar, 'close' );
            };
            if( support.transitions ) {
                navbar.addEventListener( transEndEventName, onEndTransitionFn );
            }
            else {
                onEndTransitionFn();
            }
        }
        else if( !classie.has( navbar, 'close' ) ) {
            classie.add( navbar, 'open' );
        }
    }
```